# Changing the position of a search bar when it is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

My idea is to change the position of a search bar which is in the center of a page to the upper right corner when the user clicks or places cursor in the search bar thereby making area in the center part to show the search result.

Also the cursor should remain in the search bar during transition.

this is my html, and css for the search bar

```css
.search-container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 630px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    left: 37%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -140px;
}
.search-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #b2dfdb;
    width: auto;
    height: 15em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
.searchbar-wrapper{
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
.search-bar{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<div class="search-container" id="mainpage-search">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <div class="searchbar-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="search">
                        <form class="form">
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8"><input class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for Songs"/></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><span class="btn btn-blue btn-lg"><input type="submit" id="submit-query" value="Submit"></span></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I achieve the transition?

Comment: The information you provided is not enough. Can you explain it in detail.

Comment: and you want it to return back at middle of page when the element is deselected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the way to do it with jQuery(a JavaScript library), if that is what you meant by moving it to the top.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ //when the document is fully loaded

  $('.search-bar').click(function(){ //select your searchbar by class and onclick create a new function
    var my_searchbar = $(this); //my_searchbar is how you can access your searchbar
    var my_btn = $('.btn'); //get your btn
    
    my_btn.css('display','none'); //set the css property of the submit button to "none"
    
    //create animation -60px top and 200px left
    //time is set to 1sec(1000ms)
    //after the animation is finishied create new function
    //in that functin make the submit button visible and animate it 500px to the left
    my_searchbar.animate({ marginTop: '-60px', marginLeft: '200px'}, 1000, function() {
    my_btn.css('display','block');
    $('.btn').animate({marginLeft: '500px'}, 1000);
    });
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
.search-container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 630px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 15;
    top: 50%;
    left: 37%;
    margin: -100px 0 0 -140px;
}
.search-wrapper{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #b2dfdb;
    width: auto;
    height: 15em;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
}
.searchbar-wrapper{
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-top: 70px;
}
.search-bar{
    float: left;
    width: 400px;
    line-height: 30px;

}
```

```html
<!-- add the jQuery library-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search-container" id="mainpage-search">
        <div class="search-wrapper">
            <div class="searchbar-wrapper">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="search">
                        <form class="form">
                            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8"><input class="search-bar" type="text" placeholder="Search for Songs"/></div>
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4"><span class="btn btn-blue btn-lg"><input type="submit" id="submit-query" value="Submit"></span></div>
                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, Peter. This is what I wanted. How do I add the transition animation? Can it be done?

Comment: yes, you can do anything with jQuery. Animation is done with .animate().

Comment: I edited the code. Instead of .css() just use .animate(). The animation is done in 1000ms(1sec)